# Django Rest Framework: calling sever requests four times when trying to delete using DestroyApiView

Tags: django-rest-framework

I am having an api end point which will pass the primary key and then allow the server to delete the record from the database.

I pass the request using axios from frontend.

axios.delete(http://localhost:8000/api/ingredients/276/delete).then(res
 => console.log("deleted))

I found on my server it is calling four http requests for deleting.

```
[10/Dec/2017 18:07:15] "OPTIONS /api/ingredients/276/delete HTTP/1.1" 200 0
[10/Dec/2017 18:07:15] "DELETE /api/ingredients/276/delete HTTP/1.1" 301 0
[10/Dec/2017 18:07:15] "OPTIONS /api/ingredients/276/delete/ HTTP/1.1" 200 0
[10/Dec/2017 18:07:16] "DELETE /api/ingredients/276/delete/ HTTP/1.1" 204 0
```

I think it should be only one request

Comment: how many requests are made according to the browser console.  If it matches up, then check your client API code.

Comment: As you see i am using `axios.delete(http://localhost:8000/api/ingredients/276/delete).then(res => console.log("deleted))`. I will check it

Comment: Its good practice to use HTTP verbs (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc) rather than appending to the URL.  Here, you're calling the delete method in axios, but also have `delete` in the end of the URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLDR; add a trailing slash to your request URL to avoid the unnessary redirect or remove the trailing slash from your Django urls so they match the requests happening from your browser.

The OPTIONS requests are happening because your browser is complying with the cross-origin resource sharing policy (CORS). The request is originating from a different domain than the server, so this "pre-flight" request is sent to ensure that the request is allowed.

The request is allowed, so your browser follows up with the DELETE request, however, your URL settings have trailing slashes on your routes, but your request URL does not. So you get a 301 redirect back, i.e. the location header is "/api/ingredients/276/delete/". Your browser must also verify this request via a pre-flight OPTIONS request. Finally, in your fourth request the DELETE request is fulfilled on the server with a 205 response code.

To fix, just have your client code append "/" to the initial request. This will bring the total down to 2. Alternatively, you can remove the trailing slashes from your Django URL configurations. If your URLs are being built automatically, you can modify the router: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#simplerouter.

OPTIONS requests shouldn't cost you very much, and won't be made in your production environment if your JS app is hosted on the same domain as your API server.

Comment: Alternatively, the URL configuration can be adjusted to remove the trailing slash in the url conf.  I personally really dislike resource endpoints that require a trailing slash.